# Encrypting Credit Card info on iOS app and send to server

Tags: ios, credit-card, public-key-encryption

First of all, can an iOS app collect Credit Card info and send it to the server? Will such an app be rejected by Apple?

Further questions are :-

I am developing an iOS app which takes Credit Card related info and sends it to the server. The server then processes the payment request via payment gateway.

I need to know the best/good way to encrypt this info on my iOS app before sending it to the server.
The server runs PHP with MongoDB and the server side guys are planning to use an RSA-2048 encryption.

Please guide me in this matter ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the WWDC 2012 videos there is a video called "Networking Best Practises". That video is the best way of explaining what network security you should be implementing and how to use the apple api's to do so.